# JSF PrimeFaces datatable filtering

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I 'record' objects and I put them in a `datatable`. A record has a boolean value 'Ignored', my idea is to make a filter so that it either shows all ignored records or everything. Here is my code:

```
<p:column headerText="Status" filterMatchMode="equals" filterBy="#{record.ignored}">
    <f:facet name="filter">
      <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('logTable').filter()">
        <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ignored" itemValue="#{record.ignored}" />
      </p:selectOneButton>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{record.status}" />   
</p:column>
```

For some reason it is not working properly which i could not find, after searching for some examples online.

Comment: what "is not working properly" means?

Comment: Its not showing the ignores entries when i select ignored

Answer (score 0):

The item value for this item

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Ignored" itemValue="#{record.ignored}" />
```

should be either `true` or `false` since that is the condition that will be check during the filtering of the records

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Ignored" itemValue="true" />
```